# How to commit to git with running Expo client?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, expo

I am currently learning to use *git* and *GitHub* and want to apply it to my *React Native / Expo* project. Now I am wondering how I can use `git` commands in my terminal in *VS Code* (e.g. `git commit`) when an Expo client is currently running. When I do `npm start` the client is running and I am unable to use such commands without terminating the client with `CTRL+c`. This is very inconvenient as I always have to restart the client over and over again. I believe that there must be other ways, but I could not find anything in my research.

Answer (score 2):

OK. I found a way of doing it. I add another terminal in VS Code. On one I am running the client and on the other I perform git commands. You can add another terminal by clicking on the `+` in VS Code.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to do it. You just need a new terminal window.

Comment: By the way, this is not specifically Git-related. This goes for any type of command if you're using a terminal window for anything actively, like running a server, being logged into another server, etc.